# Show nearby places on my app with Google Maps Api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I pasted this on my app:

```
// Search for restaurants nearby
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=restaurants");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

But it open Google Maps. How can do this on MY APP?

I want show in my app the nearby field of soccer.
Like this:
**But without the search bar**

[image]
[image]

i find this, but I don't understand JavaScript:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were looking at the wrong documentation. JavaScript is for web etc.

[This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) on is for android. It is Google Maps Android API v2.

You don't have to start a google maps intent. You need to create your own activity with gets the google maps fragment. For this you need a google maps api key. Again, walk through the get started.I believe you can create a maps application in android studio.  Try that

Comment: Yes but here is the code that I want: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intents Categorical Search -> // Search for restaurants nearby. But this open Google Maps, and I want this in MY app.

Comment: @facutopa Walk through the get started instead of rusing to your endpoint. You got to take some time to understand the api. See my edit.

Comment: Should i record coordinates to database, right? Maps cant save those